# Pandas append list of dicts to df2 resulting from df1.apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[19, '19-12','test1'], [20, '20-16','test2'], [21, '21-17','test3']], columns = ['de_id', 'sh_id', 'token'])
```

And this functions :

```
def get_lo(token,sh_id,de_id):

    data_ws = dl_data(token,sh_id,de_id)
    return data_ws
```

Returning a list of dicts (number of dicts can vary) with always the same structure and same keys, only data changes, example :

```
[{'id':'9','public_id':'00009','name':'John'},{'id':'10','public_id':'00010','name':'Doe'}]
```

Is it possible to do a `df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id']),axis=1)` and create a new dataframe, df2, that would have apply results merged + df1['id'] ?

Like :

```
de_id     id     public_id      name
19        9         00009       John
19        9         00010       Doe
20        56        00056       Bob
21        14        00014       Bill
```

I tried many things like `pd.concat`, `pd.merge`, `combine`, like :

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(columns=['id'])
df2 = df2.merge(df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id'])),left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

or

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(columns=['id'])
df2 = merge(df2,df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id'])),on='id,how='outer')
```

I can transform the list of dicts from get_lo() to `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` or even to a `pd.DataFrame` but can't figure out the best way to return data for each row applied on df1 so to build df2.

**EDIT - Details about dl_data()**    [anky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky)

Data from df1 is inputed to get_lo() row by row with an apply :

```
df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id']),axis=1)
```

If I try to print the output :

```
print(df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id']),axis=1))
```

I get :

```
0    [{'id': '9', 'public_id': '00009', 'name': 'Jo...
1    [{'id': '56', 'public_id': '00056', 'name': 'Bo...
2    [{'id': '14', 'public_id': '00014', 'name': 'Bi...
dtype: object
```

Type is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

**EDIT 2**

I found a temporary solution to build df2 is :

```
def get_lo(df2,token,sh_id,de_id):

    data_ws = dl_data(token,sh_id,de_id)
    for o in data_ws:
        df2.loc[len(df2.index)+1] = [de_id,o['id'],o['public_id'],o['name']]



df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['de_id','id','public_id','name'])

df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(df2,x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id']),axis=1)
```

But I think it is pretty awful et won't be performant if df1 is big

Comment: I meant how do you input the data into the function? row by row using apply? `df1.apply(lambda x: get_lo(x['token'],x['sh_id'],x['de_id']),axis=1)` ? if yes what does this output?

Comment: why don't you add `de_id` to the output of `get_lo` (inside list or dicts), loop over the the df1 axis, apply the function and create a new df based on result? If speed is the issue then I guess it can be solved using np.vectorize.

Comment: Before addind `de_id` I'd like to know how to structure the output from get_lo() to be able to add all results from df1.apply to df2